# Send php mail using emails.txt and custom message from message.txt

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to send email using PHP
I have emails.txt with a list of emails and names split by ';'
and I also have content.txt with the email message, for example, "Hello Mr. $name"

I want to send an email, for all users, using content.txt file and alter the $name using the emails.txt to replace the string $name

I built some parts, but I'm stuck

```
  <?php
    $file = fopen("emails.txt", "r");
    $filecontent = fopen("content.txt", "r");
    while(!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
        $to = $line;
         $subject = "This is subject";

         $message = "<b>This is HTML message.</b>";
         $message .= "<h1>This is headline.</h1>";

         $header = "From:abc@somedomain.com \r\n";
         $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
         $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

         $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);

         if( $retval == true ) {
            echo "Message sent successfully...";
         }else {
            echo "Message could not be sent...";
     }

    }
    fclose($file);


  ?>
```

another part

```
<?php

$path_to_file = 'content.txt';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$file_contents = str_replace("$name","$correctname",$file_contents);
file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);

?>
```

Comment: first check how many email you can send per day or per hour on your server !

Comment: I'm not sure, but the database is small.
And I will mails.txt only update with new e-mail