# recipients from text file php mail

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a emails.txt file with name and email Example: John, john@gmail.com
I can try to export with a different way the emails.txt (for example name: john email: john@gmail.com)

but the important part is
I want to send emails for all recipients that exist in emails.txt using his names to edit the message

```
$file = fopen("emails.txt",  "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        //while(!feof($file)){
        $line = fgets($file);
            $to = $line;
             $subject = "This is subject";

             $message = 'Hello Mr %NAME%!';

             $header = "From:TESTE \r\n";
             $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
             $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

             $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);

             if( $retval == true ) {
                echo "Message sent successfully...";
             }else {
                echo "Message could not be sent...";
         }


        fclose($file);
```

Comment: So what is not working? What error are you seeing?

Comment: I don't know how to split name and email... and then use on my code to send emails

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send php mail using emails.txt and custom message from message.txt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925139/send-php-mail-using-emails-txt-and-custom-message-from-message-txt)

Comment: no, here I'm asking how to split email and name from a text file

Comment: It'd be preferred if you edited your older question instead of opening a new one. It doesn't look like there's any substantial difference between the two.

Comment: Ok, Could anyone help me delete this post without any trouble or negative feedback? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)() to break up the parts of email.txt will give you what you need:

```
list($name, $to) = explode(",", $line);
$message = sprintf('Hello Mr %s!', $name);
```

This is based on every row within emails.txt being formatted correctly and clearly such as *John Smith, john.smith@example.com*

You can also change the code entirely to use [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)() which I will let you look into.

Comment: almost great! however when I'm trying to send email the script only send to the first email from txt file.

Comment: if the txt file have more emails and names separate by ',' for example John, john@gmail.com, Peter, peter@hotmail.com is possible to use the explode() ?

Comment: @joanna you have your while loop commented out so it wont do all of them. And yes, if you put the contacts on a new line it will parse through them.